# Append Custom Components dynamically in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components in react 'Tabs' and 'Tab'. Each tab component will have huge **children component or HTML elements** like form or table in the tab, so we have gone with this mark approach, instead of getting the list of tabs as props

```
 <tabs>
  <tab></tab>
  <tab></tab>
 </tabs>
```

Now my question is how can I add a new tab to the tabs when user clicks on a button. The content of the tab has to be mentioned by the user only, all I need to do is to be able to add them to the tabs component.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array containing the tabs. You append the new tab you want to add to the array and it will be shown with the new tab added. Example:

```
constructor (props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { tabData: ['tab 1', 'tab 2'] };
}
render() {

   const { tabData } = this.state;

   <tabs>
      {tabData.map(element => <tab>{element}</tab>)}
   </tabs>
}
```

When you push a new tab to the tabData state it will be added and shown.